# Intervalo de datas por número da semana

Tags: data, golang

Com esta função simples, posso obter o número da semana. Agora, com o número da semana, como posso obter o intervalo de datas, iniciado no domingo?

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    Week(time.Now().UTC())
}

func Week(now time.Time) string {
    _, thisWeek := now.ISOWeek()
    return "S" + strconv.Itoa(thisWeek)
}`
```

Toda ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo Davi! Aqui é o StackOverflow em Português. Traduza, formate sua pergunta, para que possamos ajudá-lo! ✌️

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Meu Português não é bom, desculpe.</sup>

Você pode usar [`time.(Time).Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) e depois mudar o resultado:

```golang
const (
    day       = 24 * time.Hour
    sevenDays = 7 * day
)

// weekSun returns the beginning and the end of the week of the time t in UTC,
// using Sunday as the first day.
func weekSun(t time.Time) (start, end time.Time) {
    start = t.Truncate(sevenDays).Add(-day)
    end = start.Add(sevenDays - 1)
    return start, end
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/EJMsriS0qYa.